# problemas ao recuperar o "response" de uma requisição

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

faço a requisição normalmente, mas ao tentar recuperar a resposta dessa requisição não há nenhum  retorno

```
let rqs = new XMLHttpRequest();
rqs.open("GET", "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/distritos");
rqs.send();
let dados = rqs.responseText;
console.log(dados);
```

Comment: Ajax é assíncrono, o que significa que quando a linha 4 é executada, a requisição ainda nem sequer saiu do seu computador ( a resposta somente vai chegar alguns milisegundos depois) e portanto a variável rqs.responseText está com um valor nulo (ou indefinido). Por isso o uso do callback `onreadystatechange`, para seu script ser avisado de quando a resposta chegar.

Answer (score 2):

**Tente isso:**

```js
let rqs = new XMLHttpRequest();

rqs.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rqs.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(rqs.responseText);
    }
}

rqs.open("GET", "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/distritos");
rqs.send();
```

Comment: por que o "open" e o "send" depois da instanciação do objeto? vejo muito também, depois da instanciação, a logica do script e dpois se envia a requisição, isso interfere em algo?

Answer (score 2):

**Você pode fazer dessa forma também:**

```
async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/distritos");
        const data = await response.json(response);
        console.log(data);
    }
    getData();
```

A resposta vai vir em JSON, para manipular você pode utilizar a função map ou outra que quiser.